# Terraform - Create Azure Application Targeting Two Web-Apps

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-application-gateway

I am using Terraform 1.5.5 to create an Azure Application Gateway (SKU-2) targeting two Azure web-apps under a custom domain. I need to use https in communication but am struggling around "app-gw" and "web-app" certificates and how to implement this in Terraform.

This article seems to suggest its straight forward.

[End-to-end TLS with the v2 SKU](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ssl-overview#end-to-end-tls-with-the-v2-sku)

1. Do I need to create a pfx certificate (in this case it will have to be a wildcard) to store in key-vault and then link to application gateway https listeners?
2. I have created the Terraform that creates an Azure Managed Cert for each of the 2 web-apps and bound it to the custom domain. Are the "Application Gateway Cert." and the "managed web-app certs." all required? (if all certs. are required are they related?)

Comment: Have you tried any code so far? @Ian Carrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I need to create a pfx certificate (in this case it will have to be a wildcard) to store in key-vault and then link to application gateway https listeners?

1. You could use a wildcard certificate for the domain e.g. *.wildcard.com
   Then you can use the wildcard cert for both of your custom domains.
   **Note** `both the web apps cannot be under same custom domain(cause the domain validation will fail when you try to create the custom domain as the asuid txt record will already exist.)`
   So , the wildcard certificate can be uploaded to webapp (certificate binding) and to the app gateway listener (if you store the cert in a kv then you can just link it to the app gateway and the pfx willbe pulled)

With Terraform you need to pull the versionless secret id for the secret and upload it to the app gateway for ssl.

I have created the Terraform that creates an Azure Managed Cert for each of the 2 web-apps and bound it to the custom domain. Are the "Application Gateway Cert." and the "managed web-app certs." all required? (if all certs. are required are they related?)

No, you dont need multiple certificates , this can be achieved using just self signed certificates from a key-vault.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my scenario:

For development environments I created a 'self signed' cert. and stored it in source control. When creating the Azure Application Gateway I am able to reference and link the SS cert. to the App-GW via the Terraform APPLY command.

For test and production environments I'll use a "lets-encrypt" cert. which lasts for 90. For Prod I'll try and purchase a SSL cert from a well known vendor - hopefully with a expiry dates of years.

NB: at this stage I don't think I need the Az Managed Certs. linked to the App-Service(s) so had deleted them and the web-site still works securely.